# How to get user id instead of name in Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

I have added getId method in UserIdentity class to get user id instead of username but it doestn't fetch me userid. After adding this getId method, both of the following will result as empty

```
          1. Yii::app()->user->getId();
          2. Yii::app()->user->id;
```

I posted UserIdentity class here, pls help to solve this issue

```
   class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
     {
   private $_id;
    public function authenticate()
{       
    $users= User::model()->findByAttributes(array('name'=>$this->name));
    $password= User::model()->findByAttributes(array('password'=>$this->password));
        if($users===null) {
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;                
        }
        else if($password===null) {
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        }
        else {        
            $this->_id=$users->id;   
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;

        }
        return !$this->errorCode;
}       
public function getId()
{
   return $this->_id;
}
```

}

And i tried to use CDbCriteria to get id from user model, it fetches usename column only, id column will come as empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a good solution for your case:

**check this steps:**

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/80/add-information-to-yii-app-user-by-extending-cwebuser-better-version/

after doing this steps just call this:

```
Yii::app()->user->id;
Yii::app()->user->name;
Yii::app()->user->email;
```

Comment: public function getUserId()
 {
  return $this->getState('g_user_id');
 }

Comment: This is one of methods in my WebUser class. echo Yii::app()->user->getUserId(); will gives me USER ID

Comment: NOTE: Here g_user is my table - g_user_id is PK

Comment: so you call Yii::app()->user->g_user_id or maybe you can change your attribute name from model

Answer (score 3):

you can use another method for set user id

```
else {        
        $this->_id=$users->id;
        $this->setState('user_id', $users->id);

        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;

    }
```

and call like this

```
Yii::app()->user->user_id;
```

Comment: it says Property "CWebUser.user_id" is not defined. when i use Yii::app()->user->user_id;

Comment: please confirm user_id value is set?

Comment: user_id is not set as properly,Because $users->id is doesn't have value.

Comment: if i echo $users->id, empty; if i echo $users->name, echoed as "admin";

Comment: `$users= User::model()->findByAttributes(array('name'=>$this->name));` $user get empty value?.. or `id` is not a field or attribute?

Comment: NOTE: table name in database is g_user. g_user_id as PK

Comment: $users is no t a empty value only $users->g_user_id is empty, but $users->name gives value

Comment: What actually my issue is

Comment: $criteria1=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria1->select='g_user_id, name,email,e_role_id';
$criteria1->condition='name ='."'".Yii::app()->user->id."'";
$usr = User::model()->find($criteria1);
echo "USER ID: ".$usr['g_user_id'];
echo "NAME: ".$usr['name'];
echo "EMAIL: ".$usr['email'];

Comment: USER ID:       NAME: admin      EMAIL: test@gmail.com

Comment: let me know why USER ID is echoed as empty value

Comment: check your database, is it empty?

Comment: `$users= User::model()->findByAttributes(array('name'=>$this->name)); echo "<pre>"; print_r($users);` use this code and check now is it empty? or return some values?

Comment: it finds value, but i couln't get $users->g_user_id. But $users->name teruns value

Comment: check your USER MODEL , is it same and also any conditions are there for return empty?

Comment: the following method only returns as empty in User model: public function relations()
 {
  // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
  // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
  return array(
  );
 }